# How do I duplicate "new TextView" and "setId"?

Tags: android, for-loop, int, fragment

My FragmentActivity loops and creates numerous Fragments, each with `new TextView. After some help, I have this:

FragmentActivity.java

```
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        for (int j=0; j<positionsCount; j++) {
            ...
            mTabsAdapter = new PositionFragmentAdapter(this, mViewPager);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("My Tab Name"), Fragment.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Fragment.java

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static int id = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        TextView mTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
        mTextView.setId(id);
        id++;
        mLinearLayout.addView(mTextView);

        return mLinearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        id.setText(args.get("posName").toString()); // ERROR HERE: "Cannot invoke setText(String) from primitive type int"
    }
}
```

How can I stop the error?

**Edit 2:**

```
06-11 12:54:53.843: E/AndroidRuntime(21005): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 12:54:53.843: E/AndroidRuntime(21005):    at com.example.guide.Fragment.onStart(Fragment.java:33)
06-11 12:54:53.843: E/AndroidRuntime(21005):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1484)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling setText on an integer, not a TextView. Instead of this

```
id.setText(args.get("posName").toString());
```

do this:

```
mTextView.setText(args.get("posName").toString());
```

Note that you will have to make your TextView an instance variable of the Fragment, so that it'll be accessible from other methods.

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {
    TextView mTextView;
```

Comment: Okay, that fixed the error. But the text in all the tabs changes at once still :(

Comment: Ah, I see - I think instead of setting the TextView to an instance variable, just re-instantiate it with `findViewById(id)` in your onStart method.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the line to: `TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);` and when I run it, the app crashes. It says error at line 32, which is: `tv.setText(args.get("posName").toString());`

Comment: Hmm... Try moving the `id++` part to before the `setId` part, that might fix it

Comment: Yes, that fixed it :), but the text is still updating in all the fragments :( could this be because of something inside the FragmentAdapter?

Comment: Try storing your LinearLayout in an instance variable in the Fragment code, and calling `findViewById` on that.

Comment: Still no luck. I changed it to `TextView tv = (TextView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(id);`

Comment: Okay - Try using `mLinearLayout.getChildAt(0)` instead of `findViewById`, and don't set the ID at all.

Comment: Oh - I think it's because the tabs are all using the same Fragment - I'm not sure, though, I don't have much experience with this method of using fragments.

Comment: Yeah possibly, creating individual fragments was precisely what I'm trying to avoid (a massive 139 identical fragments)

Comment: Ah, okay - that makes sense, haha. I'm not sure what the best method to do that is - Like I said, not much experience there.

Comment: Okay how about this. I just created a new android project with the nagivation type as Scrollable Tabs + Swipe. Interesting thing is, it uses two xml's: main.xml (which contains `android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip` and `</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`) and secondly, fragment.xml (which contains 1 `TextView` with ID").

Then it has one activity: Main.java - Extends FragmentActivity and when I run the App, it has unique text in each fragment textview.

Comment: Maybe, as you are much more experienced than me, duplicate the new project and guide me as to how I need to adjust my code?

Comment: @Extremis - I don't have enough time on my hands right now to actually duplicate the code and all that, but I'll be happy to help you out with adapting it. Start out with looking for the differences in the way they handle the Fragments' Views and how they add them to tabs.

Comment: Okay :) Im in the process of understanding the code right now :) is it okay if I can add you and message you occasionally if I don't understand?

Comment: @Extremis - Go to http://webchat.freenode.net/ and join the channel #extremis. :)